# Flashing textview background in android for 1 second only once

Tags: android, textview

i want flash my textview background for some interval (1000 ms), this one is killing me as i found solutions only for blinking text continuously . However i have tried this below code and it works only for first time , but  when i refresh the data after 10 seconds, it dosent flash, simply changes the color.

```
private void setBackgroundFlash(final TextView textView,
        final double oldValue, final double newValue) {

    if (oldValue > newValue)
        textView.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_FLASH_RED);
    else if (oldValue < newValue)
        textView.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_FLASH_GREEN);
    else if (oldValue == newValue)
        textView.setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    CountDownTimer timerForTextFlash = new CountDownTimer(1000, 100) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

    };
    timerForTextFlash.start();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what you want to do is? Can you explain in detail?

Comment: here is logic, i am getting values from server and displaying them in listview,this are numbers, so based on its values i want to flash  textview  with color like (green > 0 || red < 0) for one second like in stock market apps.

Comment: Hmm, check saa's answer Nubi, you will find it suitable I think.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
yourView.startAnimation(getBlinkAnimation());

public Animation getBlinkAnimation(){
        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);         // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
        animation.setDuration(300);                             // duration - half a second
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());    // do not alter animation rate
        animation.setRepeatCount(1);                            // Repeat animation infinitely
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);             // Reverse animation at the end so the button will fade back in

        return animation;
    }
```

Comment: your answer works fine for blinking textview, but i want to blink background with a color for once only

Comment: I have edited my answer. Just put any view behind textView. then apply this animation

Comment: use animation.setDuration(300); change value to increase blink time

Comment: use animation.setRepeatCount(1); change value for number of blinks

Comment: use FrameLayout and keep some empty view(What ever you like) apply animation to that empty view.